# How to grep a exact word from a variable contains sentence

Tags: bash, grep

I have tried upto my knowledge to get the result but i couldn't. I request you to guide me in a correct way.

Bellow is my bash script which is actually an init.d script.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_LEVEL="info debug_rpc warn test critical debug_sql error debug debug_rpc_answer notset"
CHECK_LOG_LEVEL=$2

logcheck() {
if [ ! -z $CHECK_LOG_LEVEL ]; then
    if [ "$(grep -o "$LOG_LEVEL")" == "$CHECK_LOG_LEVEL" ]; then
       echo "Starting the daemon with log_level"
    else
        echo "Check if the log-level argument name is correct!"
    exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "Starting the daemon"
fi
}

case "${1}" in
        start)
                logcheck
                ;;
        esac

exit 0
```

I want the grep to match the exact word. because of debug_rpc, debug_rpc_answer, debug_sql

if you user make a typo mistake by running script as:
sudo /etc/init.d/myscript.sh start debug_rp

it need to display {echo "Check if the log-level argument name is correct!"}

I am trying to match exact user argument stored in variable $CHECK_LOG_LEVE with content $LOG_LEVEL

Any guidance or workaround for this..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LOG_LEVEL="info debug_rpc warn test critical debug_sql error debug debug_rpc_answer notset"
CHECK_LOG_LEVEL=$2

# spaces below are very deliberate
if [[ " $LOG_LEVEL " != *" $CHECK_LOG_LEVEL "* ]]; then
    echo "invalid log level" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

"debug_rp" will not pass that check, but "info debug_rpc" will, if someone is determined to provide invalid input

---

for exact matching, use an array:

```
LOG_LEVEL=( info debug_rpc warn test critical debug_sql error debug debug_rpc_answer notset )
CHECK_LOG_LEVEL=$2

found=false
for lvl in "${LOG_LEVEL[@]}"; do
    if [[ $CHECK_LOG_LEVEL == $lvl ]]; then
        found=true
        break
    fi
done
if ! $found; then
    echo "invalid log level" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: yes you are right.. info debug_rpc get pass.. all i was tried to get match the argument with the words inbetween spaces....  I appriciate your reply though. but if any workaround for this.. it would be great.

Comment: Glenn.. on my test, your second code still gives found=true. if we execute the script as ./test.sh start info debug_rpc .. the array having first word (info). it because "debug_rpc" is the taken as third argument. i have to provide in script to check if any 3rd argument given by user. if so.. then exit the script with error.  Thanks anyway. I appriciate your idea. I was referring this.. :-) http://codeandfury.blogspot.in/2006/12/bash-hacks-comma-delimited-list.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `grep -qw` (match word):

```
if grep -qw "$CHECK_LOG_LEVEL" <<< "$LOG_LEVEL"; then
    echo "valid log-level argument"
else
    echo "Check if the log-level argument name is correct!"
fi
```

Afterwards you can check return status using `$?`

Comment: Probably better to suggest a direct conditional (`if grep -qw ...`) than using `$?`.

Comment: Yes of course it can be (and it should be) used directly in `if` condition.

Comment: I was going to suggest `if [ ! -z "`echo $LOG_LEVEL | grep -w $CHECK_LOG_LEVEL`" ]; then...` but this is a bit neater so +1

Comment: Any way to display the echo "Check if the log-level argument name is correct!"  only once. It is displaying for each check right now.. I appriciate the answer though.

Comment: If it is not in loop it should display once only and make sure you `exit 1` after this error.

Comment: anubhava, yours suggestion work.. but as glenn jackman said below, if user provide  sudo /etc/init.d/myscript.sh start info debug_rpc  .. it is taking to echo "valid log-level argument".   i am looking for only exact match here.. those are seperated by space. THANKS though.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment, isn't `debug_rpc` a valid input as it matches one of the words exactly.